# Excel show list based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically, I wanna do something like this :

`=IF(B1="APPLES","Show First List",IF(B1="ORANGES","Show Second List"))`

But I'm not sure how to make a proper formula.

Comment: Excel formulas are best created by starting with one component, then expanding it to another, and so on. What type of list do you want? Can you give an example of what you want to see when `B1` contains `Apples`?

Comment: It's just a simple list, such as :
1

2

3

4
and so on

Comment: Like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/EZtQq.jpg

Comment: 1 2 3 4, vertically, not horizontally!

Comment: Oh! Like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra41F.jpg

Comment: Not sure if trolling or is serious.

Comment: serious. I do find those screenshots clarity things hugely

Comment: Well you've got the formula right, all you need to do is explain what exactly you want to happen in the `"Show x List"` parts.

Comment: I just want the list to be shown?

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed? Do you want it in separate cells? All in the same cell like my second screenshot? As a drop-down menu?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8oHw9.png - Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

First create the lists:

In **C1** enter:

="Golden Delicious" & CHAR(10) & "Fuji" & CHAR(10) & "Gala"

and in **D1** enter:

```
="Satsuma" & CHAR(10) &   "Blood orange" & CHAR(10) &   "Valencia"
```

and then in **A1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="APPLES",C1,(IF(B1="ORANGES",D1,"")))
```

Turn on text wrapping and size the cells correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you got the basic formula correct, I'm going to explain the list part of the question.

We start with the basic formula you already have:

`=IF(B1="APPLES", do something, IF(B1="BANANAS", do something else, ""))`

You can skip this step, but to make it easier to understand the formula later, we're going to name the cell we want to compare in the `IF` statement. Click on the cell you want to name, then click where it says FRUIT and give it a name.

[image: Name the cell we want to reference]

This gets us to here:

`=IF(FRUIT="APPLES", do something, IF(FRUIT="BANANAS", do something else,""))`

Now we need to work on the `do something/else` part of the formula.

On a separate sheet (or anywhere, but we like to keep things clean) create the following table:

[image: FRUIT, Apples, and Bananas]

This table can have as much or as little as you like, you also don't specifically need to have the data in column A. I put that there so I can make a drop-down on the main sheet.

Once you have this data table, you can start filling in your formula more. We're going to look at the first `do something` part. To do this we need to reference the cell that has the value we want. Because it's on a separate sheet, we need to specify that it's `Sheet2` and cell `B1`.

`Sheet2!B1`

We then substitute `do something` with `Sheet2!B1`.

`=IF(FRUIT="APPLES", Sheet2!B1, IF(FRUIT="BANANAS", do something else,""))`

This will grab `Apples1` as it's the first value in column B on `Sheet2`.

We then do the same for `do something else`:

`=IF(FRUIT="APPLES", Sheet2!B1, IF(FRUIT="BANANAS", Sheet2!C1,""))`

After this you just need to drag the formula down as far as you want to create the list making sure you have enough values in your reference sheet, and at this stage we're done!

[image: Final Formula in practice]

Comment: Could use more [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775)

Comment: @bertieb The arrow was sorta freehand using the line tool.

Comment: Partial credit.